# Reversing the bytes of a unicode txt file

Tags: c#

I have a file 1.txt in Unicode. The text of the file: "12345"
If you read bytes from it to a byte array, you will get 12 bytes:

> 255 254 49 0 50 0 51 0 52 0 53 0

That's fine.
What I can't understand is that if I reverse bytes like this:

> 0 53 0 52 0 51 0 50 0 49 254 255

C# method `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteArray)` returns `㔀㐀㌀㈀㄀�` and that's correct, but notepad shows `5 4 3 2 1юя`, why?

You can find byte reverse method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Comment: Did you find the interpretation to `255 254`? It might be something that indicates the beginning of a file, and when reversed, you just get this weird Chinese character.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is why notepad displays `5 4 3 2 1` in first place, while in code it gives weird unicode characters as it is supposed to (or that's what author expects at least)

Comment: Unicode, generally, ends up with *multi-*byte encodings - why would you expect reversing the bytes of such a file to be in any way meaningful?

Comment: 1) read about first two bytes below
2) I expected to get Chinese characters in the txt file but I don't, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text file is probably encoded as UTF16.

The two bytes at the front are the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and aren't part of the text.

You must not alter them. So what you should do is skip the first two bytes and reverse the remainder of the bytes.

But that will also give you problems because you can't just reverse the bytes in a UTF16 code - it will give you the code for a completely different character, or indeed an invalid code.

Anyway, what's happening when you reverse the order is that you wind up with the BOM stuck at the end where it forms an invalid UTF16 code that happens to be the "?" character at the end that you're seeing, and also it messes up the encoding for all the other characters.

However, it looks like **Notepad** is opening the file using an ANSI encoding, probably for the code page used by your current locale.

The text file contains bytes `0 53 0 52 0 51 0 50 0 49 254 255` and Notepad is converting 0 to a space, and the other values less than 0x80 are being converted to ASCII characters, while 254 is converted to `ю` and 255 to `я` (which I assume is the value of those characters in the ANSI code page for your current locale).

I'm guessing you're in a Slavic region which uses Cyrillic script.

Comment: Looks more like UTF-16LE than UTF-8. And the Chinese characters come from the endianness swap, not the misplaced BOM. And of course the conclusion should be that you cannot reverse a Unicode string by reversing the bytes.

Comment: 1) ok I've got it about two BOM

Comment: 3) The point is I have to get Chinese characters in the txt file but I don't, why?

Comment: @MaxNevermind It's because the text file contains bytes `0 53 0 52 0 51 0 50 0 49 254 255` and Notepad is converting `0` to a space, and the other values less than 0x80 are being converted to ASCII characters, while `254` converted to `ю` and `255` to `я` (which I assume is the value of those characters in the ANSI code page for your current locale)

Comment: Oh yeah Notepad opens the file in ANSI encoding nevertheless that I saved it as UTF-16. Thanks!